# Focal Person Meaning

Tags: word-meaning

> The meeting also decided to nominate **focal persons** from both sides who will coordinate with officials in Pakistan and Iran for resolving issues of pilgrims during their travel from Quetta to the border and from there to holy sites in Iran.

Can someone please elaborate the term 'focal person'. I tried to run a search for it on google but could not find any mention of it on any website. What I got was the meaning of focal which does not seem to fit in this term. Thank you!

Comment: Where did you find the term? Please give us the context.

Comment: I found it in a newspaper. It reads, 'The meeting also decided to nominate focal persons from both sides who will coordinate with officials in Pakistan and Iran for resolving issues of pilgrims during their travel from Quetta to rhe border and from there to holy sites in Iran.'

Comment: The underlying noun ***focus*** is *a point of convergence of a beam* (of light, etc.). The cited text ["to nominate focal persons"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22to+nominate+focal+persons%22&tbm=bks&sxsrf=ACYBGNQl9ZZacRKrns1rmyYl7R36kBwYmg:1575994411339&source=lnt&tbs=sbd:1&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiH37jYvKvmAhVXVRUIHUfmBUUQpwUIIQ&biw=1689&bih=910&dpr=1) (which doesn't occur *anywhere* in Google Books) is a metaphoric reference to assigning *people* (native speakers would rarely use *persons* in such contexts) through whom communications are "channeled, coordinated, focused".

Comment: https://www.pakistantoday.com.pk/2019/10/20/polio-focal-person/ A term used in Pakistan to mean contact person.

Answer (score 1):

*Focal person* doesn't have a special meaning apart from the literal words.

Google provides a good definition of *focal*:

> relating to the center or main point of interest.

So *focal person* as it's used in your example would mean "person who is the center or main point of interest."

I get the feeling "leader" is what's truly meant/desired, but a neutral term has been used to prevent communicating that anyone has more power than anyone else.  Business communication does this thing all the time across hierarchical boundaries (compare with the business-speak use of the word "partner", for example).

Answer (score 0):

In the context that you have provided, it appears to be the "public face" for the group. Focal means, "[of, relating to, being, or having a focus](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/focal)" So the person having the focus for the group would be the person representing, answering questions, etc.

Comment: It's an unusual expression, but it seems to mean 'the person on whom attention is focussed'.

Comment: That's pretty much what I said.

Comment: This term is used in Pakistan, so this answer is probably right:https://www.google.com/search?sxsrf=ACYBGNSjTDbHH-Oey0hIF7puali0RzIemQ%3A1575999682714&ei=wtjvXc6VK6LO5gLKlafwCA&q=%22focal+person%22+%2B+pakistan&oq=%22focal+person%22+%2B+pakistan&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i22i30.24937.26626..27055...0.1..0.150.927.2j6......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71.DLo_v64xHxs&ved=0ahUKEwjO_oOq0KvmAhUip1kKHcrKCY4Q4dUDCAs&uact=5

Answer (score 0):

It means contact person or public affairs person. At least, in Western countries that is what would be used.

[Pakistani usage](https://www.pakistantoday.com.pk/2019/10/20/polio-focal-person/)

> Too late the hero? The Prime Minister’s Focal Person for Polio
>   Eradication, Ata Babar, has resigned, citing personal reasons, rather
>   than the sixfold rise in polio cases this year that should have seen
>   him booted out anyway.